# Python decorator prints in reverse when passing in a function call?

Tags: python, function, decorator, wrapper

Still learning Python, and today I was messing around with decorators in IDLE when I saw some behavior that I did not understand. I defined a simple decorator, and when decorating my test function it all works as expected:

```
>>> def decorator_function(original_function):
        def wrapper_function():
            print("wrapping")
            return original_function()
        return wrapper_function

>>> def test_function():
        print("wrapped function")

>>> decorated_test = decorator_function(test_function)
>>> decorated_test() 
wrapping
wrapped function
```

But then I tried to remove the call to `original_function` and pass in the call to `test_function`, and strangely enough (for me) this reversed the print statements:

```
>>> def decorator_function(original_function):
        def wrapper_function():
            print("wrapping")
            return original_function
        return wrapper_function

>>> def test_function():
        print("wrapped function")

>>> decorated_test = decorator_function(test_function())
>>> decorated_test() 
wrapped function
wrapping
```

I have tried to get my head around it, but can't figure out what really happens. If something, I would expect it to only print `"wrapping"` as `test_function` would `return None`.

Comment: because in your call `decorator_function(test_function())` the `test_function` is called (which prints `wrapped function`) and then `decorator_function` is called with the return value of that which is `None`

Comment: I guess I was doing some overthinking when trying to understand this. I did not realize that the passing of a function call executed the function and printed the result. Thank you @kuro